# Does Oracle LISTAGG work with GROUP BY and PIVOT?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pivot, listagg

I have this table:

```
ID     CATEGORY     SCORE
-------------------------
1       A            2
1       B            1
```

and am trying to get the avg(score) for each category:

```
ID     SCORE_A_AVG  SCORE_B_AVG
------------------------------
1       1.5         1.5
```

I've tried this but all results are null

```
select p.* from (
        select ID, LISTAGG(CATEGORY, ',') within group (order by CATEGORY), avg(score) score
        from foo
        group by ID)
PIVOT (avg(score) score
FOR category IN ('A' as A_AVG, 'B' as B_AVG)) p;
```

I can get results for one or the other category by NOT using LISTAGG:

```
... MIN(CATEGORY) ...
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       avg(case when category = 'A' then score end) as score_a,
       avg(case when category = 'B' then score end) as score_b
from foo
group by id;
```

I have no idea why you are thinking `listagg()` rather than `avg()`.

Comment: My example is basic but I need to pivot the results.

Comment: @mrcrag . . . This answers the question that you have asked.  It does pivot the results, but using a simpler syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does work but you need the aggregation in the `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   test_data
PIVOT (
  AVG( score ) AS avg_score,
  LISTAGG( score, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY score ) AS scores
  FOR category IN (
    'A' AS a,
    'B' AS b
  )
)
```

So for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( ID, CATEGORY, SCORE ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'B', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'B', 2 FROM DUAL
```

this outputs:

> ```
> ID | A_AVG_SCORE | A_SCORES | B_AVG_SCORE | B_SCORES
> -: | ----------: | :------- | ----------: | :-------
>  1 |         2.5 | 2,3      |         1.5 | 1,2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d92041eb0997ec7ff13e709baad9579a)*

Comment: Thanks, Gordon and MT0. I think both solutions will work and answer my question. I'm selecting Gordon's answer as he posted first. His solution is less elegant when plugged in to my actual query but that's not on him.